# Bluegiga BGScript blinkylight example

Tags: bluetooth, 8051, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm trying to code BGScript but I have some questions. Can you help me?

I have DKBLE112 which is Development Kit of the BLE112 module built around the CC254x, an 8051 derivative with an on-chip BLE transceiver. And my questions are as following.

I could to blink a LED by using an example code below. But some lines are unclear to me.

The first is below.

```
# setup port 2 pin 1 for the switch output
call hardware_io_port_config_direction(2,$2)
```

The comment say pin 1. Why $2 is pin 1?  And how can I change to use P2_2?

The second question is this.

```
call hardware_io_port_write(2,$2,$2)
```

Why the setting data is $2? (I changed $1 but not blinked)

Thanks,

```
dim led

event system_boot(major,minor,patch,build,ll_version,protocol,hw)   
    call hardware_spi_transfer(0,16,"  Blinky Light  ")

    # setup port 2 pin 1 for the switch output
    call hardware_io_port_config_direction(2,$2)

    # turn port pin off
    call hardware_io_port_write(2,$2,$0)

    led = 0

    call hardware_set_soft_timer(32768,0,0)
end

event connection_disconnected(handle,result)
    call gap_set_mode(gap_general_discoverable,gap_undirected_connectable)
end

event hardware_soft_timer(handle)

    if led > 0
        call hardware_io_port_write(2,$2,$0)
        led = 0
    else
        call hardware_io_port_write(2,$2,$2)
        led = 1
    end if
end
```

Comment: What is BGScript?

Comment: It's a front end language for an interpreter or support components running on an 8051 derivative with a proprietary BLE transceiver that otherwise has only binary radio driver libraries only compatible with an overpriced & buggy windows-only C compiler.

Comment: It seems likely that in BGscript port pins count from 0 (as they do on the CC254x chip itself and the 8051 family in general) therefore pin 0 has a place value of 1, pin 1 a value of 2, pin 2 a value of 4, and so on.

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/123630/bluegiga-bgscript-accelerator-sample-i-want-to-understand-the-example-code

Answer (score 1):

I've got a fair amount of BGScript experience and I have some (semi) documented example scripts here: https://github.com/sureshjoshi/ble113-firmware-examples

As a general statement, using $1 or $2 in those APIs is to get the specific PIN on a PORT. So, you're essentially doing a bitmask.

$1 is pin 0, $2 is pin 1, $4 is pin 2, etc...

If you want to access multiple pins at once, you would use the appropriate value. E.g. 3 in hex is 0x03 (or $3 in BGScript), which is also 0b00000011, which sets pin 0 and pin 1.

In the embedded world, you'll need to do a lot more of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29

If you look through the documentation of the device you're using, they will specify what the functions of each pin at each port are.